# What is the simplest way to expand a plan from frequency and due date using Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of activities, next due dates and frequencies at which the activities happen and would like to expand this plan out to a specified date.

I was trying to do this using Pandas with the following example data frame:

```
  Activity   NEXTDATE  FREQUENCY
0        A 2020-01-31         12
1        B 2020-03-31         24
2        C 2020-05-31         36
```

The frequency column is the number of months between each instance of the activity. For example, activity A should occur every 12 months on 31st January until the selected end date.

If the selected end date was 1st January 2025, I would like the output to be something like:

```
enddate = datetime.datetime(2025, 1, 1)
plan = expand_plan(df, enddate)
print(plan)


   Activity   NEXTDATE  FREQUENCY
0        A 2020-01-31         12
1        B 2020-03-31         24
2        C 2020-05-31         36
3        A 2021-01-31         12
6        A 2022-01-31         12
4        B 2022-03-31         24
8        A 2023-01-31         12
5        C 2023-05-31         36
9        A 2024-01-31         12
7        B 2024-03-31         24
```

Is there a simple solution? Or even, is there a better way than using Pandas?

Comment: What is the logic of your expansion? Can you elaborate? For example, why does 2021 has 1 row?

Comment: @Erfan It looks like the `frequency` column is the next date in months . So it looks like `C` occurs in three years which is why it does not appear again until 2023. At least that is my interpretation. So something like: `df['NEXTDATE'] +  df['FREQUENCY'].astype("timedelta64[M]")`

Comment: I've added more information on the frequency in the question. Yo_Chris' interpretation is correct. How would you expand the data frame to include the repeating activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In no way do I believe this to be the best solution as it will be very slow on large frames, but nevertheless...

```
# define your months to add
months = 12*4 # 4 years
# months mod  freq +1
df['repeat'] = months // df['FREQUENCY']+1
# zip your columns together 
z = list(zip(df['Activity'], df['NEXTDATE'], df['repeat'], (df['FREQUENCY'])))
# list comprehension to fill data into pd.date_range
l = [pd.DataFrame({'NEXTDATE': pd.date_range(d, periods=p, freq=f'{int(y/12)}Y'),
                   'ACTIVITY': [a]*p,
                   'FREQUENCY':[y]*p}) for a,d,p,y in z]
# concat your list of dfs
df2 = pd.concat(l)
# assign columns

# sort values
df2.sort_values('NEXTDATE')

    NEXTDATE ACTIVITY  FREQUENCY
0 2020-12-31        A         12
0 2020-12-31        B         24
0 2020-12-31        C         36
1 2021-12-31        A         12
2 2022-12-31        A         12
1 2022-12-31        B         24
3 2023-12-31        A         12
1 2023-12-31        C         36
4 2024-12-31        A         12
2 2024-12-31        B         24
```

Comment: Thanks! Although, when testing it doesn't quite perform as expected. All dates are 31st Dec and the expanded plan doesn't always end when expected e.g. if another activity was added to the example data frame with FREQUENCY = 36 months, NEXTDATE = 2024-1-1, it would appear twice when it should only appear once.